# IndexError: list index out of range python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Trying to run this code :

```
sorted_by_name = sorted(sort_array,key=lambda x:x[0]))
```

I get:

> IndexError: list index out of range

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well one of element in the `sort_array` should be either empty or null string. See the below examples

Example #1:

```
sort_array = ['abc', 'acd', 'abcd', '']
sort_array
['abc', 'acd', 'abcd', '']
sorted(sort_array, key=lambda student: student[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

For example #2, i will take sort_array as list of lists, which matches more to your example of `sorted_by_name`

```
>>> student_tuples = [
...         ['john', 'A', 15],
...         []
... ]
>>> sorted_by_name = sorted(student_tuples,key=lambda x:x[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Hence I request you to please check your input `sort_array` once, if it has any empty lists

Answer (score 0):

That means that at least one thing in your list is empty so doesn't have a first element.  The fix is simple, don't pass a key:

```
sorted_by_name = sorted(sort_array)
```

The default implementation of `sorted` already tries the first item, then the second item, the third item, etc.  When you pass it a key, it first tries your key, the first item.  If it finds that two are the same, it does its own check.  It checks the first item (again), the second item, the third item, etc.  In other words, both are the same except that supplying a key might mean that the first item is checked twice, and of course the default implementation doesn't error on an empty list.